# Zend Framework 2 SQL Join Issue

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to use two left outer joins with Zend Framework 2's SQL classes but for some reason it is not returning one result but the other one is working fine. I've ran the actual SQL in MySQL Workbench and it returns just like I want but it is not doing it with Zend Framework. Here is my code:

Pure SQL:

```
  SELECT groups.group_name, members.username, groups.id FROM groups
  LEFT OUTER JOIN group_admins ON groups.id = group_admins.group_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN members ON group_admins.user_id = members.id
  WHERE group_admins.user_id = " . parent::getUserId()['id']
```

This returns the result I wish, (which can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq9Sg.jpg)

Now, here is the Zend Framework 2 code I have in place:

```
$select_admins = new Select();

$select_admins->from(array(
    'g' => 'groups',
))
->join(array(
    'ga' => 'group_admins'
),  'g.id = ga.group_id')
->join(array(
    'm' => 'members'
),  'ga.user_id = m.id', array('username'))
->where(array('ga.user_id' => parent::getUserId()['id']));


$query_group_admin = parent::$sql->getAdapter()->query(parent::$sql->buildSqlString($select_admins), Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

$group_admins = array();

foreach ($query_group_admin as $group_admin) {
    $group_admins[] = $group_admin;
}

// get the group members
$select = new Select();

$select->from(array(
    'g' => 'group_members'
))
->join(array(
    'm' => 'members'
), 'g.member_id = m.id')
->join(array(
   'grp' => 'groups'
), 'g.group_id = grp.id')
->where(array(
    'g.group_id' => $group_id
));

$query = parent::$sql->getAdapter()->query(parent::$sql->buildSqlString($select), Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

$member_username = array();

foreach ($query as $member) {
    $member_username[] = $member['username'];
}



// get the rest of the group info
$fetch = $this->gateway->select(array(
    'id' => $group_id
));

$row = $fetch->current();

if (!$row) {
    return false;
}

return array(
    'admins'  => implode(", ", $group_admins),
    'members' => implode(", ", $member_username),
    'info' => $row
);
```

Controller:

```
public function grouphomeAction()
{
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

    if (0 === $id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('members/groups', array('action' => 'index'));
    }

   if (!$this->getGroupsService()->getGroupInformation($id)) {
       return $this->redirect()->toRoute('members/groups', array('action' => 'index'));
   }

   return new ViewModel(array('group_info' => $this->getGroupsService()->getGroupInformation($id)));
}
```

However, this only shows the group name, group creator and group members but leave the group admins field empty.

Here is the print_r result of the array returned:

```
Array ( [admins] => [members] => jimmysole, fooboy [info] => ArrayObject Object ( [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [id] => 2 [group_name] => Tim's Group [group_creator] => timlinden [group_created_date] => 2017-01-16 17:39:56 ) ) )
```

If it helps, here is a screenshot as well of the page - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmdYL.jpg

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your joins are INNER JOINS...I know....you must hate Zend right now :p . By default they are INNER JOINS so i assume that is what is wrong. SO try to specify the type of join and you should be fine. You can find more examples here: [examples](https://gist.github.com/ralphschindler/3949548)

```
$select12->from('foo')->join('zac', 'm = n', array('bar', 'baz'), Select::JOIN_OUTER);
```

Comment: It's saying I have a sql syntax error. I don't know if it makes a difference but Select::JOIN_OUTER_LEFT is returning OUTER LEFT JOIN but the mysql manual says its LEFT OUTER JOIN. 

The Exception is:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER LEFT JOIN `group_admins` AS `ga` ON `ga`.`user_id` = `groups`.`id` OUTER L' at line 1

Comment: Here is the code I have in place right now after viewing your examples

$select_admins
        ->from('groups')
        ->join(array('ga' => 'group_admins'), 'ga.user_id = groups.id', array('ga_user_id' => 'group_admins.user_id'), Select::JOIN_OUTER_LEFT)
        ->join(array('m'  => 'members'), 'ga.user_id = m.id', array('m_username' => 'm.username'), Select::JOIN_OUTER_LEFT)
        ->where(array('id' => $group_id));

Comment: Sorry in my understanding you cannot perform LEFT OUTER JOIN.  It either LEFT or OUTER... Check the documentation for the select class to confirm... Maybe you can run a raw query instead? In order to achieve the necessary results?

Comment: I did switch outer join but got the same result:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN `members` AS `m` ON `ga`.`user_id` = `m`.`id` WHERE `groups`.`id` = '' at line 1

Comment: assuming you are doing something like here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html then please note that if you do not include columns in these files they will not be displayed in results. If this is not the issue i dont know what exactly is. It should work with what we discussed by now.